# "Vertex paint" or Cycles "Mix node" problem?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, vertex-paint

[image]

I sure I should see blue texture in place of this blue/green jitter.
Why this happens?

Comment: What does it look like when you switch to Object mode? Any difference?

Comment: The same. Render looks exactly like preview, too.

Comment: Ok, maybe post your blend, can't see issue from screenshot.

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/np3dyxx

Comment: Could you please download it to [pasteall](http://pasteall.org/blend) or [blend-exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) ?

Comment: I'm sure it's happens cause mesh too heavy... Still, isn't it should just "work"?

[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=360" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/360/)

Comment: Hm, I removed ~75000 doubles and it changed, but still looks weird - some polys still get wrong material. UPD. Oops my fault, after Remove doubles one should once more paint Vertex Paint, and it's [better now](http://i.imgur.com/LNqzhno.jpg)

Comment: Oh, I see now - whole mesh is two-sided, so I paint only one side, and the painted AND clear one overlapping in render. Thank you, It's just ugly mesh that caused problems.

Comment: same conclusion, remove doubles, recalc normals and vertex paint is ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having such problems with mask created by **Vertex Paint**:

1. First check whether there are double vertices (<kbd>W</kbd> >
   *Remove doubles*).
2. Recalculate normals with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>. The result
   is better but still weird, something like:

   [image]
3. Continue using **Vertex Paint**, simply drawing over these gaps and
   smoothing boundaries and it's done.